# Can't find my.cnf on my VPS

Tags: linux, mysql, vps, centos5

Hello, I am currently renting a VPS for the purpose of host a magento store. The VPS is running Centos5 with DirectAdmin.

I have read a bit about how to optimize magento and one suggestion I have seen is to edit the MySQL configuration file. However, I cannot find this file anywhere from within DirectAdmin. Also, I cannot connect to the VPS via SSH. My host has a root access via their website but it won't let me enter my root password.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading and installing [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) assuming you're using a Windows PC - you should be able to use this to connect directly to the command line of your server as the root user. If this doesn't work then you should contact your VPS hosting provider and let them know. Its possible that they may not have configured your account properly.

Once you're logged in then you can find all files on your VPS called my.cnf using the following command:

> find / -name my.cnf

Normally on a centos machine this file is located somewhere in /etc

> find /etc -name my.cnf

will search just the /etc folder and be much quicker

Comment: Ok i tried putty just input the hostname and port 22 plus SSH connection type.... console appears asking for login as. I chose admin then it asks for password but as with their website based console, it won't let me type a password... the cursor won't move.

Comment: The cursor doesn't move when you are entering a password.  This is to prevent exposing information about your password (such as its length).

Comment: Agreed.  Also, you should add this as a *comment* to Xoundboy's post, not as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The standard location is:

```
/etc/my.cnf
```

Also, if you are on Windows, download Putty. Then, run Putty and enter your server's IP address. It will ask you for a user name. Type "root" and press enter. Then, It will ask you for a password. Type it in and press enter. To edit the MySQL configuration file type this command:

```
vi /etc/my.cnf
```

If you do not know how to use vi. There is an excellent tutorial available here:
http://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/vi.html

Comment: I just realized that this question is almost a year old.